# generate mst which is contain standard properties automatically

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I want to generate a MST which is automatically come standard properties and ect, using template. How can i do any script (vbscript, IS script or powershell) ?
I am using installshield. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For generating MsiTran.exe available. You get it, when installing the Windows SDK (or included in Visual Studio).

With `msitran -g` you can easily generate transforms.
With `msitran -a` you can easily apply transforms e.g. in batches or scripts, of course also those transforms you have created with InstallShield or other tools.

Like everything in MSI, MsiTran parameters are quite good documented. Search for documentation in the internet (MSDN) for this tool.

It is worth mentioning, that despite popular belief to the contrary, you can define transforms independently from ProductCode, UpgradeCode, etc.
This allows to use that .mst like a general "diff" or in other words an automatic edit.

You can just add the rows and columns in MSI you need for an example MSI of your choice (best is a simple small one), apply MsiTran which takes the difference of "original MSI" and "edited MSI", and saves the result in a transform.
This can serve as a "template" for all other MSIs, if you have used the correct parameters.

(Technically these diffs are SQL commannds/queries for the MSI database, but this shouldn't bother most times.)

Second important thing to mention is, that transforms contain error configuration. E.g. if you add a property by a transform, and the property does already exist, an error can be thrown or not.
I want to avoid such errors in most cases, because e.g. it is possible to apply a transform a second time without error. But on the other Hand they can give a good test, if your MSI is like what you expected.
The error configuration can be set by documented commandline Parameters too.

Like mentioned you can create, view and edit transforms of course also with graphical tools like 
InstallShield or Insted.

Intelligent edits where you want to change some fields dependent on logical conditions are not directly possible with transforms. For that you can use classical programming. Most admins to this with with script languages like VBS or JScript, etc. Many examples out there.